# Duplicate class attributes in one HTML file

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm helping in documenting a software project using sphinx. We want to cover the 13 classes all in one HTML file. It's handy.

My problem: Some classes have identically named attributes (see 'width' and 'weight' in the two classes below).
In the resulting HTML doc file clicking on the property 'width' will always jump to HTML anchor '#width', regardless of the class I'm looking at.

Is there a way to have sphinx generate unique anchor names?

```
:mod:`GSFontMaster`
===============================================================================

Implementation of the master object. This corresponds more or less with the "Masters" pane in the Font Info.

In Glyphs.app the glyphs of each master are reachable not here, but as :class:`Layers <GSLayer>` attached to the :class:`Glyphs <GSGlyph>` attached to the :class:`Font <GSFont>` object. See info graphic on top for better understanding.

.. class:: GSFontMaster

.. autosummary::

    name
    id
    weight
    width
    weightValue
    widthValue
    custom
    customValue
    ascender
    capHeight
    xHeight
    descender
    italicAngle
    verticalStems
    horizontalStems
    alignmentZones
    guideLines
    userData
    customParameters

----------
Properties
----------

.. attribute:: id

    Used to identify :class:`GSLayer <Layer>` in the Glyph

    :type: unicode

.. attribute:: name

    :type: string

.. attribute:: weight

    :type: string

.. attribute:: width

    :type: string

.. attribute:: weightValue

    Values for interpolation in design space.

    :type: float

.. attribute:: widthValue

    Values for interpolation in design space.

    :type: float

.. attribute:: custom

    :type: string

.. attribute:: customValue

    Values for interpolation in design space.

.. attribute:: ascender

    :type: float

.. attribute:: capHeight

    :type: float

.. attribute:: xHeight

    :type: float

.. attribute:: descender

    :type: float

.. attribute:: italicAngle

    :type: float

.. attribute:: verticalStems

    List of vertical stem values

    :type: list

.. attribute:: horizontalStems

    List of horizontal stem values

    :type: list

.. attribute:: alignmentZones

    Collection of :class:`GSAlignmentZone <GSAlignmentZone>`.

    :type: list

.. attribute:: guideLines

    Collection of :class:`GSGuideLine <GSGuideLine>`.

    :type: list

.. attribute:: userData

    A dictionary to store user data. Use a unique Key and only use object that can be stored in a Property list (string, list, dict, numbers, NSData) otherwise the date will not be recoverable from the saved file.

    :type: dict

.. attribute:: customParameters

    A dictionary of custom parameters

    :type: dict



:mod:`GSInstance`
===============================================================================

Implementation of the instance object. This corresponds more or less with the "Instances" pane in the Font Info.

.. class:: GSInstance

.. autosummary::

    active
    name
    weight
    width
    weightValue
    widthValue
    isItalic
    isBold
    linkStyle
    customParameters

----------
Properties
----------

.. attribute:: active

    :type: bool

.. attribute:: name

    :type: string

.. attribute:: weight

    :type: string

.. attribute:: width

    :type: string

.. attribute:: weightValue

    Values for interpolation in design space.

    :type: float

.. attribute:: widthValue

    Values for interpolation in design space.

    :type: float

.. attribute:: isItalic

    Italic flag for style linking

    :type: bool

.. attribute:: isBold

    Bold flag for style linking

    :type: bool

.. attribute:: linkStyle

    Linked style

    :type: string

.. attribute:: customParameters

    A dictionary of custom parameters

    :type: dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the classname: so the `width` attribute of `GSFontMaster` should look like:

```
.. attribute:: GSFontMaster.width

    :type: string
```

(The autosummary entry has to be adapted according to the full attribute name.)